# the rider dismounted the bus

Tags: word-usage

When a passenger gets off a bus, would I say:

- The rider dismounted the bus
- The rider left the bus.
- The rider got off the bus.
- The rider exit the bus.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The rider **dismounted** the bus.

Is not correct, a bus rider does not *mount* a bus.
(S)he usually **gets on** / **jumps on** / **hops on** / **catches** a bus.

> The rider **left** the bus.
>   The rider **got off** the bus.
>   The rider **exited** the bus.

Are all appropriate to describe a rider who is no longer on the bus.

It's not usually said that a rider **entered** the bus.

EDIT: It can also be said:

> I was on the bus and **got out at** Charing Cross Station.

Comment: I think you could say *entering* a bus, but emphasizes moving into the physical space enclosed by the bus. In my experience *get on/off* is the most common usage.

Comment: Of those three, I think "got off" is the most common, at least in conversation. In a formal announcement, though, I think I might prefer _to exit_, e.g.: _"Please use caution when exiting the bus."_

Comment: I concur. "Got off" is probably the most common.

Comment: My (somewhat casual) observation is that **exit**(AmE) and **alight**(BrE) are frequently used when passengers are addressed by an anonymous voice over a PA system: "Passengers may alight at Westminster for the Jubilee line" or "Passengers must be in the first five cars to exit at South Ferry".

Answer (score 0):

You may find this verb useful:

> [**alight**](https://www.google.com.hk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ALIGHT)
>
> *verb*
>   [formal]
>
> descend from a **train, bus**, or other form of transport.

"Visitors should alight at the Fort Road stop."

Similarly,

> "The passenger **alighted** the bus."

Moreover, I think it isn't precise to use **dismount** and **rider**, because:

> [**dismount**](https://www.google.com.hk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=dismount+meaning)
>
> *verb*
>
> 1.get off a **horse, bicycle, or anything that one is riding**.

and,

> [**rider**](https://www.google.com.hk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=rider+definition)
>
> *noun*
>   1.
>   a person who is riding or who can **ride a horse, bicycle, motorcycle**, etc.

I'm not saying that those two words are entirely wrong or inappropriate, I am providing more 'precise' words, re: definition [passenger and alight].

Answer (score 0):

**disembark**

to leave an aircraft or other vehicle

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/disembark?s=t

**debus**

to get out of a bus; alight from a bus

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/debus?s=t

The rider disembarked.

The rider debussed.